# Why is my logcat full of "I/System.out"?

Tags: android, logcat

We have an application that is still in the debug phase and does quite a bit of logging, using `Log.d()` and similar. The app has recently been installed on a customer device (of a type similar to what we use) and it crashes quite early. Obviously it runs fine on our device.

We had hoped to find out why from the logging info, but the logcat is full of lines that look like this.

> 06-19 17:04:58.060: I/System.out(1915): com.appname/.SplashScreen
>   06-19 17:05:05.655: I/System.out(1915): com.appname/.SplashScreen
>   06-19 17:05:05.900: I/System.out(1915): com.appname/.SplashScreen
>   06-19 17:05:05.900: I/System.out(1915): com.appname/.SplashScreen
>   06-19 17:05:05.905: I/System.out(1915): com.appname/.SplashScreen

Here `appame` is the package name for our app and `.SplashScreen` is the startup activity.

There is enough information in the log to tell us that it crashed at `setContentView(id)`, but most of the information that should be in the log leading up to that point is nowhere to be found.

We do not have access to the device at present so we're running on not many clues. The question is whether this occurrence of unexpected entries in the log file indicates any specific problem we can investigate further. For example, is there a specific reason why an app cannot write to the logcat? Could it be related to a reason why the app might crash?

---

We are aware that this message can be caused by calls to System.out.println. I guarantee there is not a single System.out.println anywhere in our code.

A big chunk of the app is NDK C++ running on a worker thread that is started from an Application class. The C++ code writes its own log files, but has no way to (intentionally) write to standard out.

---

I still don't have an answer, but it does seem that these messages come from Java libraries or other code not under our control. There seems to be no harm in ignoring them.

Comment: are you starting a background thread in splashscreen that never ends??

Comment: There is a worker thread started in the Application class (before the splashscreen). Why do you ask?

Comment: Have you tried ACRA?
By the way, you get System.out-s because you are writing something out with System.out.println somewhere.

Comment: We're about to try ACRA, without a great deal of confidence. See edit.